# Echo Input Item

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a reasonably straight forward set of inputs that are used for placing orders.

Basically, it calculates the quantity * price for them.

However, on the bottom near a submit button, I want to show the total price plus which items they have ordered. Is there a way using JQuery or similar, that I can basically echo out the associated h6 content of the item that they have placed a number in the quantity field for?

I already have the total cost working fine.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <h6>Title</h6>Text.
    </td>
    <td id="price_item_1" class="menuprice">$PRICE</td>
    <td class="quantitynum">
        <input type="text" name="qty_item_1" id="qty_item_1" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td id="total_item_1" class="runningtl"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: where are you calculating quantity * price?

Comment: i have a javascript function that calculates quantity * price and places in class runningtl. However, I just dont know how to show the h6 tag content if quantity > 0.

Comment: can you either post your calculation code or link a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you calculate the total every time the quantity value changes, what you could do is inside the function where you calculate the total, to check for the quantity value, and act accordingly:

```
if (quantity > 0)
   $("h6").show(); // assuming there is only one h6 in the page, otherwise you have to add ids to each h6
else
   $("h6").hide();
```

Comment: Kind of, but there is a summary at the bottom of the form, that shows total and asks for their name etc. Each item has a h6 tag associated to it. For example, I can use $('h6').html() to echo the tag, but no idea how I would wrap and repeat this for every item whereby quantity > 0

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I would make, rather than looking at a different element for each input, store the title text as an attribute on the `input` itself. The `title` attribute is perfect for this.

With that in mind, the following code snippet should work:

## HTML:

*Simplified slightly for clarity. I've added classes to the form, the inputs and the summary element.*

```
<form class="order-form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" title="Product 1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" title="Product 2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="quantity" title="Product 3"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="order-form-summary"></div>
</form>
```

## Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  // Find all of the DOM elements we're interested in:
  var form = $('form.order-form'),
      output = form.find('.order-form-summary'),
      inputs = form.find('input.quantity');

  // Bind a custom event handler to the form, that collects the titles from the
  // inputs with a value > 0
  form.bind('updateSummary', function(){

    // Collect the titles into an array
    var summaries = $.map(inputs, function(e){
      var input = $(e);
      if (parseInt(input.val()) > 0){
        return input.attr('title');
      }
    });

    // Update the output element's HTML with the array, joined to a string with commas.
    output.html(summaries.join(', '));
  });

  // Fire the update event whenever chance, key-up or blur occurs on any input
  inputs.on('change keyup blur', function(){form.trigger('updateSummary')});

  // Fire it on load to get the correct starting values (in case any inputs are already filled)
  form.trigger('updateSummary');
});
```

This code could be condensed, but I've aimed to leave it readable. Here's a fiddle with the example: https://jsfiddle.net/ejwLy5x8/